# How to combine Hover, Out, Click event together

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegates

```
var bar = $('.div_layer_Class');
  $('a.second_line').click(function() {
      $(this).unbind('mouseout');
  }).mouseover(function() {
      bar.css('display','inline');
  }).mouseout(function() {
      bar.css('display','none');
  });
```

now the issue with 'onBodyclick' when i click anywhere on body again i want to invoke `mouseoutevent` something like this

```
$('body').click(function() {
      bar.css('display','none');
 event.preventDefault();

  });
```

when I do this it overlaps `$('a.second_line').click(function()` event. any idea how I can Achieve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/qGJH4/56/

Comment: Your hover isn't working :(  I'm not sure if you are able to attach multiple events by chaining them like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/qGJH4/81/)
Try changing your code to this

```
var bar = $('.div_layer_Class');
$('a.second_line').click(function(e) {
    bar.addClass('on');
    e.stopPropagation();
}).mouseover(function() {
    bar.css('display','inline');
}).mouseout(function() {
   if(!bar.hasClass('on'))
       bar.css('display','none');
});

$(document).on('click',function(){
  bar.removeClass('on');
  bar.css('display','none');
  //return false;
});
```

Two lines to look at, first, the e in `function(e)`

```
$('a.second_line').click(function(e) {
```

and the stop `e.stopPropagation();`

That basically stops any parent handlers being notified. [Read here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: thanks for your input now the problem with mouseover and out please check it here. http://jsfiddle.net/qGJH4/61/ it works fine very first time

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't see that line... I have update the answer with a link to an example.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `e.stopPropagation()`,
you can do 2 things:

- make a variable to reference the mouseout event handler so you can re-bind it whenever the user clicks elsewhere to the body.
  or
- A variable to store to whether a.second_line is focused or not. Something like
  `var focused = false;`

You code now will be:

```
var bar = $('.div_layer_Class');
var focused = false;
$('a.second_line').click(function(e) {
    focused = true;
    e.stopPropagation();
}).mouseover(function() {
    bar.css('display','inline');
}).mouseout(function() {
    if (!focused)
        bar.css('display','none');
});

$(document).click(function(e){
    bar.css('display','none');
    focused = false;
});
```

Comment: @LeeR - I'm a newbie here. Thanks though. :)

Comment: @LeeR - is there any other way insted of using  `$(document).click(function(e){` because it gives error when i implement with my project

Comment: @user1060990 what error is it giving you? You could try `$('html, body')` but without saying what your error is, it makes debugging it difficult.